# CreateThread parameter value changes unexpectedly

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, visual-c++

Im trying to create 4 threads to run a function simultaneously at my 4 CPU cores. The function i call will change some loop offsets depending on `val` variable value.

I tried this, but it doesnt increase the `val` counter properly, some of the threads report same values, it seems to change randomly:

```
int val = 1;
threads[0] = CreateThread(0, 0, my_thread_1, &val, 0, 0);
val++;
threads[1] = CreateThread(0, 0, my_thread_1, &val, 0, 0);
val++;
threads[2] = CreateThread(0, 0, my_thread_1, &val, 0, 0);
val++;
threads[3] = CreateThread(0, 0, my_thread_1, &val, 0, 0);
```

But this seems to work just fine:

```
int val1 = 1;
int val2 = 2;
int val3 = 3;
int val4 = 4;
threads[0] = CreateThread(0, 0, my_thread_1, &val1, 0, 0);
threads[1] = CreateThread(0, 0, my_thread_1, &val2, 0, 0);
threads[2] = CreateThread(0, 0, my_thread_1, &val3, 0, 0);
threads[3] = CreateThread(0, 0, my_thread_1, &val4, 0, 0);
```

What could be the reason for this, and how is it properly done to give some parameter to a thread?

This is my function:

```
DWORD WINAPI my_thread_1(void *params){ 
    int val = *(int *)params;
...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This fails simply because in your first example you are passing the pointer to the *same memory location* for all 4 threads. The fact that you incremented the *value* before passing the *pointer* is inconsequential, as the memory location stays the same.

In your second example you instead pass 4, *mutually exclusive pointers* to the 4 threads. Therefore, the threads all read independent values.

You could restructure your code slightly to help with maintainability and flexibility:

```
int threadData[NTHREADS]; /* in the future this could be an array of structs */
HANDLE threads[NTHREADS];
int tt;

for (tt = 0; tt < NTHREADS; ++tt)
{
    threadData[tt] = tt + 1; /* placeholder for actual logic */
    threads[tt] = CreateThread(
        NULL,            /* lpThreadAttributes */
        0,               /* dwStackSize */
        my_thread_1,     /* lpStartAddress */
        &threadData[tt], /* lpParameter: each thread will receive its own data */
        0,               /* dwCreationFlags */
        NULL             /* lpThreadId */);
}

/* Since threadData and threads are local to the enclosing scope,
 * we must wait for them to finish here to ensure we don't read
 * data we no longer own
 */
WaitForMultipleObjects(NTHREADS, threads, TRUE, INFINITE);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you're passing the same object to all threads. In the second case, you're passing different objects.

In both cases, there is a potential problem that if the function which creates threads returns, then all the created threads will have pointer to `int` which doesn't exist anymore, because all `int` objects are local objects to the function which created the threads. This invokes undefined behavior.

So if the function doesn't wait and returns, then in that case, you shouldn't pass pointer to local object, instead pass dynamically allocated object:

```
int *v1 = new int;
threads[0] = CreateThread(0, 0, my_thread_1, v1 , 0, 0);
```

Comment: I see, so, the second example will be guaranteed to work properly, if my function that creates those threads wont die before my threads have stopped?

Comment: @Rookie: Yes. If the function which creates threads doesn't return until the threads finishes their job, then it is well-defined.

Comment: Sure, or you wait until all the threads have eaten up the value passed and either no longer need it or have made local copies.

Comment: @martin, yeah i am using WaitForMultipleObjects()

Comment: @Rookie: That is perfect (assuming you're using it correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple threads are accessing the same memory at the same time. You should use a mutex or a semaphore for exclusive access to the variable in critical sections.

Comment: nevertheless, is the second example guaranteed to work properly?

Comment: Locks are absolutely not the answer here. The answer is not to share data. That's always preferable to locks and it's semantically the right thing here too.